# PHP curl see raw post content

Tags: php, curl, request

I am using PHP curl and i am trying to send data with the content type multipart/form-data.

However, something goes wrong, and i want to compare the request in the browser and my curl request. The problem is, is can see all sent header with curl_getInfo(), but not the raw post data. How can i see this?

I want to make sure everything in my curl request is exactly the same as in my browser request.

```
Apparently i have to add some code or else i can't post this
```

Comment: You have `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` option set to `true`?

Comment: Yes, but i am interested in the post body i sent, not the headers i receive.

Comment: What don't you just var_dump the content you put into POSTFIELDS?

Comment: Because i get a different response from the browser than from my curl request so i need to know that the request is exactly the same. All the headers are already, so i assume it has something to do with the body.